# Are there any HD Bitcoin mobile wallets with the mnemonic seed in traditional Chinese?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, open-source, mobile, mnemonic-seed

If not, what would be the easiest way to modify an open source iOS/Android wallet (eg copay) to do this?

Comment: I found this: https://bitcore.io/api/mnemonic/ but not sure how compatible this is with copay code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the bip39 for traditional Chinese word list.

https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/chinese_traditional.txt

Also, there are some useful pages that explain how to implement Mnemonic code for generating deterministic keys as following,

https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bip39

https://iancoleman.io/bip39/#chinese_traditional